# How to retrieve GET parameter in Twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I'm attempting to retrieve a GET request variable for use in a twig template.
For instance if you go to the page myurl.com/node/64?name=Dave I want the page to render

```
<h1>Dave</h1>
```

However I'm having trouble retrieving this variable. I've attempted

```
<h1>{{app.request.get('name')}}</h1>
```

In my twig template but it turns up empty.
How would I retrieve a GET variable from within a twig template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You didn't say what template this is for, but `app` is not defined in any of the templates I have seen.

What you could do, is add a theme_preprocess_TEMPLATE function to include the GET params. Here is a page template example:

In your mytheme.theme file, add a hook_preprocess_page function.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page()
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['get']['name'] = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Then in your page.html.twig you can render it like this:

```
<h1>{{ get.name }}</h1>
```

Comment: My template is actually a block template and I can't seem to get access to the variable from preprocess_page. I tried doing the same thing in preprocess_block but the block template can't seem to see any variable I create for it.

Comment: Did you rebuild the cache after adding the hook?

Comment: yes. As I test I did mymodule_preprocess_block(&$variables){ $variables['test'] = 'testing'; }  and inside my template {{ test }} but it came out null. I tried it as $variables and $vars.

Comment: Your theme is called mymodule? Can you paste your code?

Comment: It's within a module. http://pastie.org/private/ktrcvaloe6ref8qd1j5a I'm just trying to get anything to paste to it from the hook at the moment. The block is rendering just fine, it's just not pasting anything from the $variables array.

Comment: Is the block using your template file? I only ask because blocktemplate.html.twig is not the standard naming structure.

Comment: It is using that template file. I have a theme hook that is directing the block plugin to use that template.

Comment: Here's some more code showing where I'm directing that http://pastie.org/private/4ssutdb48mh2n4opixayig

Comment: If you add your own template called newsarchive, then it's ...preprocess_newsarchive, not block.

Comment: Note that in this case, I would actually recommend you just pass along that from the request object in your block: #name => \Drupal::request()->query->get('name'), make sure you define it as well in your hook_theme(). And last note, the xss filtering is not needed, that would only result in double escaping. auto-escape takes care of that

Comment: Does not work for me!

Comment: Removed xss filtering from my example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Twig function to achieve this. E.g:

```
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('getQueryArg', [$this, 'getQueryArg']),
        ];
    }

     
    public function getQueryArg(string $argName): string|int {
      return \Drupal::request()->query->get($argName);
    }
}
```

In TWIG you would call it as: `{{ getQueryArg('name') }}`

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html